# Duplicat data exctraction issue from PDF using python

Tags: python, regex, pdf, screen-scraping

Good day,

I'm trying to extract quantity,product codes and the document number from pdf document lines using regex and sorting them with nametuples.

My script is stuck in some form of loop.
The pdf document only has one document number  but for each product code there will be a quantity.
What am I doing wrong?

PLease see attached image.

Below is my script:

```
import re
import csv
import itertools
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from io import StringIO
from collections import namedtuple
import datetime

# Prompt user to select PDF file to scrape
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
filepath = askopenfilename()

# Define regex pattern to match lines with 1-3 digits followed by a period
digit_pattern = re.compile(r'^(?P<digit>\d{1,3})\.\s*$')

# Define regex pattern to match Product codes
product_code_pattern = re.compile(r'^(600[0-9]{10})')

# Define regex pattern to match Document Numbers
document_number_pattern = re.compile(r"^\d{3}#0*\d{9}$")

# Initialize PDF resource manager and text converter
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
sio = StringIO()
codec = 'utf-8'
laparams = LAParams()
converter = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, sio, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, converter)

# Extract text from PDF and search for lines that match the pattern
with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(file):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    lines = sio.getvalue().splitlines()
    digit_matches = [line for line in lines if digit_pattern.match(line) and digit_pattern.search(line).group('digit')!='0']
    product_code_matches = [line for line in lines if product_code_pattern.match(line)]
    document_number_matches = [line for line in lines if document_number_pattern.match(line)]

# Create namedtuples and add matches
Invoice = namedtuple('Invoice','qty product_code document_number')
invoice = []
for digit_match, product_code_match, document_number_match in itertools.product(digit_matches, product_code_matches, document_number_matches):
    invoice.append(Invoice(digit_match, product_code_match,document_number_match))

# Save results to CSV file with current date and timestamp
now = datetime.datetime.now()
filename = f"Output_{now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')}.csv"
with open(filename, mode='w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(Invoice._fields)
    for row in invoice:
        writer.writerow(row)
# Clean up
converter.close()
sio.close()
print(f'Scraped data saved to {filename}')
```

I want to scrape quantity,product code and document number from pdf documents and have them sorted with namedtuples

Below are the output data using the print statement:

Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6005277000108', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6005277000788', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6005277000115', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6005277000122', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009880839056', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009888389102', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009888389119', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6005277001501', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009880839100', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6005277000023', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009888389157', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009880839322', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009880839902', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009880839940', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009880839872', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009880839797', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009880839827', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009880839421', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009880839414', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009880839957', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009880839759', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6005277009453', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='24.', product_code='6009880839742', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6005277000108', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6005277000788', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6005277000115', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6005277000122', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009880839056', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009888389102', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009888389119', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6005277001501', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009880839100', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6005277000023', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009888389157', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009880839322', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009880839902', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009880839940', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009880839872', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009880839797', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009880839827', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009880839421', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009880839414', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009880839957', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009880839759', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6005277009453', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='10.', product_code='6009880839742', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='20.', product_code='6005277000108', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='20.', product_code='6005277000788', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='20.', product_code='6005277000115', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='20.', product_code='6005277000122', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='20.', product_code='6009880839056', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='20.', product_code='6009888389102', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='20.', product_code='6009888389119', document_number='228#000009083')
Invoice(qty='20.', product_code='6005277001501', document_number='228#000009083')

so basicly it repeats qty until all the product codes has been scraped and then moves onto the next QTY and starts at the top with the product codes .

Comment: Can you share the pdf you are trying to scrape?

Comment: Which loop is it stuck in? You could add some `print` statements to debug your code.

Comment: @MukeshIngham apologies for the late response I've amended my original post. It gets stuck in a loop on the qty field

Comment: @O-O-O I've added the output data using the print statement as er Mukesh suggested hope this helps